# WP7 MediaPlayerLauncher Forward Button behavior

Tags: windows-phone-7, video-streaming, media, playback

I am using MediaPlayerLauncher to play a video URL that is retrieved from server. The video plays with no issues. When I click on the backward button, the user skips back 5 seconds through the clip. But when I click on the forward button, it skips to the end of the clip(is this the default behavior?). But when the forward button is clicked, I want the clip to jump forward 5 seconds as the backward button does(backward button allows user to skip back 5 seconds through the clip). Is there anyway we can change the forward button behavior?

Comment: does the video that you're playing support seeking?

Comment: Can you tell me how to check whether a video supports seeking ?

Comment: Yet another reason to use MediaElement in this situation - MediaElement.CanSeek (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.canseek%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot alter the behavior of the default system media player and it will react to user input as it is defined in the OS and not in the application you are working with. Your best bet here would be using a [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=VS.96%29.aspx) instead, but you will have to implement all playback controls on your own.

Also a good read on the topic: [Media Overview for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402550%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's defintiely possible to skip forward in movies played with the MediaPlayerlauncher. I've only tried this with moviews downloaded to and played from IsolatedStorage. (I've also not tested this in Mango but don't expect it to have changed.)

This behaviour is not user configurable.

I suspect that the behaviour is dependent upon whether the file being played supports skipping forward.

Comment: can you tell me how to check whether a video supports skipping forward ?

Comment: Try MediaElement.CanSeek (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.canseek(v=vs.96).aspx) It'll also depend on if the "movie" is being streamed.